# Find the parent css and change the code inside it [Wordpress]

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am new website developer and even newer to Wordpress. I have a bug which is on  [this page.](http://holybible.deeksleem.net/gallery/)

You can see that the images have an opacity of 0.3 and that is because the parent div has a style that says opacity: 0.3. 
My question is how I can find that code in my files so I can remove the opacity and give it an opacity of 1 instead of 0.3.

This is a plugin called Sizron Facebook Album and the theme I am using called the7. The problem is probably from the7 theme as when I switched to an old theme, there wasn't a problem.

Note: I tried to add in my style.css an opacity:1; for the .image_wrapper, the div and the image but didn't work.

Would highly appreciate anyone that guides me on how should I look for file I need to edit.

Thanks in advance for everybody :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

place this in your style.css

```
.Image_Wrapper {
opacity: 1!important;
}
```

The !important will override the opacity:0.3 so you dont have to find the right file.

note : when updating your theme all files in your theme will be back to standard. 
Creating a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) would fix this problem.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks so much for the help but it doesn't seem to work. Should I consider a child theme or what? 

I am looking for the fastest method. Any thoughts?

Comment: @JamalJubran This should normaly work. Is your style.css placed in the correct map? + Child theme: for good security on your website you need theme updates. but updates override your theme files. so everything you created in css will be lost on updating.  for an easy way you can also try the plugin : Custom Css

Comment: Hi 

It worked! I think it was working but it was cached or something like that so I opened the page in incognito and it was good :)

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

I cant see your code but if you add the rule !important after your opacity:1 it should do the job.

```
.Image_Wrapper{
opacity: 1!important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your CSS?

```
.Image_Wrapper {
    opacity: 1!important;
}
```